# When using dyn.load in R I do not get any error messages, but my .dll file does not load

Tags: c++, r

I am following an example from the 'Writing R extensions manual' version 3.3.1. Specifically, I am working with c++ code, which I have saved in file out.cpp, that is on page 115 of that manual shown below:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
  SEXP out(SEXP x, SEXP y)
  {
    int nx = length(x), ny = length(y);
    SEXP ans = PROTECT(allocMatrix(REALSXP, nx, ny));
    double *rx = REAL(x), *ry = REAL(y), *rans = REAL(ans);
    for(int i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
      double tmp = rx[i];
      for(int j = 0; j < ny; j++)
         rans[i + nx*j] = tmp * ry[j];
      }
 UNPROTECT(1);
 return ans;
 }
```

I have a windows computer and use cygwin command line. There I typed R CMD SHLIB out.cpp and get the following result:

```
cygwin warning:
MS-DOS style path detected: C:/R-3.2.3/etc/x64/Makeconf
Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/R-3.2.3/etc/x64/Makeconf
CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this       warning.
Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
g++ -m64 -I"C:/R-3.2.3/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/RCompile/r-       compiling/local/local323/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c out.cpp -o     out.o
g++ -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o out.dll tmp.def out.o -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib -LC:/R-3.2.3/bin/x64 -lR
```

I think there is nothing wrong with this, right? Then when I go into Rstudio I type

```
dyn.load(paste("C:/Rextensions/out",
           .Platform$dynlib.ext, sep = ""),local=FALSE)
```

which gives me no error message whatsoever. But when I run

```
is.loaded('out')
```

I get 'FALSE', so I am never able to upload out.dll. Could you help me with this please?

P.S.: I know how to run functions like this one using Rcpp, so please don't tell me to do that instead. What I am trying to do is understand really well the Writing Extensions manual so I hope I can go through all of their examples in that document.

Thank you.